# Write dict of dict to CSV with one key/value per row with keys filling columns

Tags: python, loops, csv, dictionary, key

I want to write a dictionary of dictionaries to a CSV file,
with one key/value per row.

The dictionary looks like this:

```
d = {'animal':{'reptile':['lizard', 'snake']},'food': {'meat': ['bacon', 'lamb', 'beef']}}
```

The desired CSV file would be like this:

```
animal,reptile,lizard
animal,reptile,snake
food,meat,bacon
food,meat,lamb
food,meat,beef
```

My code:

```
import csv
d = {'animal':{'reptile':['lizard', 'snake']},'food': {'meat': ['bacon', 'lamb', 'beef']}}

f= open('file.csv', 'w', newline='')
with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:  
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
    for key, key2s in d.keys():
        for key2, values in d.items():
            for value in values:    
                writer.writerow([key, key2, value])
```

I know there is something wrong with the for-loops here and I tried variations and still got stuck. I have searched and read some posts but haven't found an answer that helps my situation. Can you please point out what I missed here?

Comment: Try just printing d.keys() - you'll see its just the keys of the outer dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the value from each loop as the thing to iterate through in the next loop. Also, both loops need to use `items()`, not `keys()`.

```
for key, value in d.items():
    for inner_key, inner_value in value.items():
        for item in inner_value:
            writer.writerow(key, inner_key, item)
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you Daniel! I got confused about the loop. Right, it should be items for things to loop in, be it inner items or outer items.

Comment: This would've saved my butt like two weeks ago! Glad I found it eventually though.